# How to assign git commit hash to a variable in Jenkins File

Tags: git, shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to  assign the git commit hash to a variable defines in Jenkins pipeline as follows

```
GIT_COMMIT_HASH = sh "(git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%H')"
```

This will print the commit hash in Jenkins build log but it fails to assign the value.

When I try to print the value using

```
steps{
    script {
                GIT_COMMIT_HASH = sh "(git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%H')"

                echo "**************************************************"
                echo "${GIT_COMMIT_HASH}"
                echo "**************************************************"
    }
}
```

This will results null

How may I assign the value ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to tell the sh script to return stdout back to your script, rather than just dumping it to stdout.

```
GIT_COMMIT_HASH = sh (script: "git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%H'", returnStdout: true)
```

Comment: Its not gonna work Im getting an error
sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Comment: You must have something typed incorrectly. I'm guessing you missed a comma.

Comment: Oops. Forgot the label for the first variable. I think it is "script". Fixed above.

Comment: I just validated this with some of my scripts. This is the correct syntax now. Sorry, I should be more careful with my copy/paste editing.

Comment: copy-pasting this into osx's bash is a no-go

Comment: @ofloveandhate this is for a linux server

Comment: `git rev-parse HEAD` is a faster way of doing this

Comment: @ofloveandhate This is something you would put in your `Jenkinsfile`, not paste at the shell prompt. The shell command is the fragment `git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%H'` which will work fine in Bash if you have `git` installed. As suggested in the previous comment, you could replace it with a faster command, too.

Answer (score 6):

Under [https://<your_jenkins_hostname>/env-vars.html/](https://%3Cyour_jenkins_hostname%3E/env-vars.html/) there is a page showing the list of the env-variables available in each build.

They might depend on your plugins, but if you are using git in your pipeline then you probably have the right one to have the `GIT_COMMIT` env variable available.

Comment: To the downvoter: sorry, maybe I did not provide enough background before. Edited. Can you re-review please?

Comment: always better to compare the asked date

Comment: Compare it to what, @co2f2e? I don’t get your point. Anyway, am I missing some reason noone is suggesting a built-in variable?

Comment: awesome! Stupid Jenkins hiding this info in stack-overflow. TeamCity makes this information a first class result of the build.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a helper function and then call it within your pipeline

```
def getCommitSha() {
  return sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD')
}

// to an env var
env.GIT_COMMIT_HASH = getCommitSha()

// to a var within the pipeline
GIT_COMMIT_HASH = getCommitSha()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this inside the environment block

GITCOMMIT="${sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD')}"

Answer (score 0):

Although the `GIT_COMMIT` variable is present in my https://%3Cyour_jenkins_hostname%3E/env-vars.html/ as suggested by @GregDubicki is his answer, actually the variable was not present during pipeline execution. Maybe this is because I'm using a manually configured checkout step.

So I had to modify that step a bit to extract the Git commit hash. Like this:

```
stage('Checkout SCM') {
    steps {
        script {
            // Here we save the result of the `checkout` operation to a local variable
            def scmVars = checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                      branches: scm.branches,
                      doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: scm.doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations,
                      // These are my custom options, for which I had to use the manual checkout step. These might not be necessary for your case.
                      extensions: scm.extensions + [
                              [$class: 'LocalBranch'],
                              [$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: false],
                              pruneTags(true),
                      ],
                      submoduleCfg: scm.submoduleCfg,
                      userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs
            ])
            // Here we save the Git commit hash into an environment variable
            env.GIT_COMMIT = scmVars.GIT_COMMIT
        }
    }
}
```

Now in later steps the `GIT_COMMIT` environment variable can be used as usual, for example:

```
stage('Build') {
    steps {
        echo "Building on git commit = ${GIT_COMMIT}"
    }
}
```

Inspired by [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/950721/79200).